# How to wait for request method in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to perform several iteration functions and cant get over node.js async type of work.

```
async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
       // function gets amount of pages
    },
    function (amountOfPages, callback) {
        //addes a url to each page
    },
    function (links, callback) {
        //Now i need to go over each link , and extract info from that page 
        var tradelinks = [];
        async.each(links, function (link, callback){

            console.log("In loop : "+ link) // Until this part its doing all right , then it hangs on the request 

            request(link , function (error, response, body) {
                //extract from page... 
            })
            callback()
        })
        callback(null, tradelinks);
    }
], function (err, result) {
    console.log("Done")
    console.log(result)
});
```

Basically it does the first two functions in right order , then it goes all over the links and doesn't wait for the request function execute , so im getting a blank array in the result and `done` flag and only after that , it prints the data extracted from the pages .

My output is looking like this

```
Function 1 done
Function 2 done
In the async.each loop // for how many links there are
Done
[] //only after this point the data extracted from page appears
extracted data // for how many links there are
```

My new with this kind of programming , and dont really know how to proceed from here.I know this can be done with promises or something of that kind , but i cant seem to get it working.

Comment: async.each() is missing it's complete callback (which is where waterfall iteration callback should be called)

Comment: Try using `cb` instead of `callback` in `each` loop. `async` will consider that waterfall step is finished..

Comment: tried using cb , didnt work .what do you mean by missing it's complete callback?

Comment: @Pure_eyes, Use third argument in `.each` as `, function done() {//...}` and pass your `callback(null, tradelinks);` there.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre yup that did it , can you explain why though ?

Comment: It notifies that each iteration is done and waterfall can move over next step..Earlier it was getting breaked after first each iteration..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue appears to be that you're issuing the `callback(null, tradelinks)` outside of the flow of async. You need to make it in the callback of your `.each`, it notifies that each iteration is completed:

```
async.each(links, function() { stuff here }, function() {
  callback(null, tradelinks);
});
```

Comment: Are you sure ? Wont is break the `each` and process the next waterfall step ?

Comment: Can you explain why does it require it?

Comment: Because the code will continue the entire synchronous path before it handles any of the asynchronous code. If the callback is called outside of the async library, it's part of the sync code, so it will get called before any of the async functions respond.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that request is also async. Here is what you are doing:

```
    async.each(links, function (link, callback){

        console.log("In loop : "+ link) 

        request(link , function (error, response, body) {
            //I am async too. And I just fire off and async.each
            //processes the next item in the array, fires me off again,
            //and never waits for me to complete. You really need to 
            //put async.each's callback inside me and all will be well.
            //Also, change async.each's callback to cb because while
            //Javascript's functional scope makes it ok, it's still
            //confusing to read.
        })
        callback()
    })
```

So, the new code should do this an you'll be okay.

```
    async.each(links, function (link, cb){

        console.log("In loop : "+ link)

        request(link , function (error, response, body) {
            //do stuff synchronously
            cb() 
        })

    })
```

Answer (score -1):

In async call work with callback function in the stack. Look this:

```
function init(){
    /* 1- stack */
    async("any data", function(data){
        first(data);
    });
}

function async(data, callback){
    /*
    .
    . Code async
    .
    */
    callback(data);
}

function first(data){
    /* 2- stack */
    async("any data", function(data){
        second(data);
    });
}

function second(data, callback){
    /* 3- stack */
    async("any data", function(data){
        third(data);
    });
}

function third(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: When working multi async function, is necessary callback function. In my example showing this